# How to include Database in C# application when it runs in new computer after it is installed on that computer?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2012

I made a C# based application that use SQLCommand, SQLConnection and SQLAdapter (SQL objects) with  database named "base1".
Problem is that, SQL is installed in my PC along with Visual Studio, so App recieve no problem in connecting itself to base1 for transaction of data.

Now, i want to make setup of this application. I want to add "base1" in this setup so that when new user install this application, app can easily connect with base1.

Comment: Entity Framework would automagically handle this

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use [SQL Server CE (Compact Edition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact). It means you have only db file (.mdf) and two dll files (containing SQL Server CE library) attached additionaly to your app. Of course, then you should use SqlCeConnection instead of SqlConnection class and so on.

Answer (score 0):

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032(v=sql.100).aspx) on how to embed SQL Server into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can use LocalDB which is installed with VS every time. So you will always have a server as (localdb)/v11.0 on your computer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLITE to make your application portable.if not you have to add the SQlserver installation to your application install. But this method needs configuration with avery installation in a new computer.